# How to find the weights and biases for a basic decision boundary?

Tags: neural-networks

I am having trouble understanding what should be a very basic concept, for finding the weights and biases for a single-layer perceptron, when given a decision boundary.

Assume that:
$$p1 = [1 \ 1]^T,\ 
p2 = [-1 -1]^T, and\ 
p3 = [2 \ 2]^T$$

And the intercepts are at:
$$ (3,0) \  and \  (0, 3) $$

How do I find appropriate weights and biases given the decision boundary shown below?  I know that it's a simple usage of the intercepts, but I am having trouble applying that to this example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is intended as a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question?

Going by [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), it looks like the decision boundary would be defined by
$$f(x_1,x_2)=w_1x_1+w_2x_2+b=0$$
So you can plug in your two known points on the boundary, i.e. $f(3,0)=0$ and $f(0,3)=0$. This is two equations for the three unknowns $w_1,w_2,b$.

Then note that only the *sign* of $f$ matters, so the decision boundary does not change if you multiply $f$ by any positive constant.

Does this help point you in the right direction?

Comment: This does help!  The weight vector is orthogonal to the decision boundary, so choosing values for w1 and w2 which satisfy this will be critical too.  Thanks!